# Java JVM time zone names via java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, jvm, timezone

Javadocs on  java.text.SimpleDateFormat state the following on the "z" pattern letter:

> z     Time zone   General time zone   Pacific Standard Time; PST; GMT-08:00
>
> General time zone:  Time zones are interpreted as text if they have names. For time zones  representing a GMT offset value, the following syntax is used ...

Question is - "if they have names" ... where does it get these names from?  I have seen in one environment JST coming up as "JST" and in another coming up as "GMT+9"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Timezone names are embedded in the JVM.  They come from the [tz](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) database maintained by Arthur David Olson.  Disparities between timezone names are caused by JVMs using different versions of the tz database.  Sun provides a [Timezone updater tool](http://java.sun.com/javase/tzupdater_README.html) for its JVMs which you can use to update the timezone name definitions.  Of course its always better to use the latest JVM update, but this is not always an option.

Comment: If this is true then how can I get a list of names that my specific JVM uses ? And how does java.text.SimpleDateFormat pick an entry from this list when there are multiple matches (e.g. CST can be Cuba Standard Time or China Standard Time, but java.text.SimpleDateFormat on my JVM thinks it is Central Standard Time) ?

Answer (score 0):

It should support time zone display names as defined by the **LDML**
([**Unicode Locale Data Markup Language**](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/) ) specification.

You will find all the names in [Time Zone Localization](http://unicode.org/cldr/data/docs/design/formatting/time_zone_localization.html), especially in "[**aliases**](http://unicode.org/cldr/data/docs/design/formatting/zone_log.html)"