# Java ResultSet how to getTimeStamp in UTC

Tags: java, jdbc

The database has data in UTC and when I try to get data

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(PUBLISH_TIME);
cal.setTime(ts);
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: You tell us, you're the one asking the question. Have you actually tried it? Does it not give results that you were expecting? If yes, then what were you expecting, and what were the results that it gave? And what does the database tell you when you use its own query tool?

Comment: Yes I tried it, yes it is not giving the results that I am expecting. The database has UTC value and this code further add +8 to the already existing value in DB.

Comment: What is the DB? Have you tried with other DB? do you know resultSet.getTimestamp(PUBLISH_TIME,Calendar.getInstance()); possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your DateFormat instance is most likely displaying the value in local time.  When displaying your value, give this a try:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(PUBLISH_TIME);
cal.setTime(ts);

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

EDIT: to your comment:

> What if I use GMT, would that be an issue in SimpleDateFormat

[SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#timezone) can use general timezones (GMT +/- n), [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822), and text ("if they have names" as the JavaDoc states - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613942/java-jvm-time-zone-names-via-java-text-simpledateformat) for info on the names).

Comment: What if I use GMT, would that be an issue in SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 35):

```
java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
java.sql.Timestamp ts = resultSet.getTimestamp(PUBLISH_TIME, cal);
```

This should do the trick!

Comment: Note that as per the documenation at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28int,%20java.util.Calendar%29 this will work only if the underlying database does not store timestamp information

Comment: @arahant, if the underlying db stores timezone (not timestamp) information then there's no problem as the timestamp will be in the correct timezone.  The problem is when the timestamp is stored in UTC without timezone information, as Java will use the local machine's timezone to construct the timestamp object.

Comment: (very late) Warning! This method will kill your milliseconds - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24081377/609452

Also, if you are multi-threading, make sure you don't try to "optimise" by sharing the timezone calendar - for some twisted reason, the implementation modifies the calendar to construct the reply

Comment: If `resultset.updateTimestamp(column, mili)` first then `resultset.getTimestamp(time, cal)` throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff] `.  Been struggling with this issue for a while.

Comment: @paul what happens if the timezone is NOT set on the DB server, and if we don't pass calendar in the rs.getTimestamp as second parameter. Will the timestamp in the db column be treated as UTC ?

Comment: @krishna: In this case, JDBC will use a default calendar to construct the timestamp, which leads to *hard* problems around the DST switch time.

Comment: You can directly instantiate a UTC calendar as follows and avoid the `setTimeZone` call:

`java.util.Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`