# Android:Timestamp is not displaying device time

Tags: java, android, timestamp, chat, timestamp-with-timezone

Hi I need to display the timestamp but i didn't get the proper output here is my coding can you check my code and correct my mistakes.My code displays only UTC time not device time.

```
// show dateTime

        viewHolder.dateTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        DateTime createdAt = message.getCreatedAt();
        LBLog.v(TAG, "createdAt = " + createdAt.toString());
        LBLog.v(TAG, "createdAtMillis = "  + createdAt.getMillis());
        DateTimeFormatter fmtTimeBubble = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(LBUtil.TIME_AM_PM_FORMAT);
        viewHolder.dateTime.setText(fmtTimeBubble.print(createdAt));
    }

    // update divider here
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(LBUtil.MONTH_DD_YEAR_FORMAT);
    DateTime dividerDateTime = message.getCreatedAt();
    viewHolder.dividerTextView.setText(fmt.print(dividerDateTime));
```

Please check this I need a timestamp like this:
[image link](http://www.actualidadiphone.com/2012/11/16/whatsapp-se-actualiza-y-ya-es-compatible-con-el-iphone-5-y-ios-6/)

Comment: May be this post can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469256/java-resultset-how-to-gettimestamp-in-utc

Comment: so I remove the DateTimeFormatter?

Comment: First open a new project and run that example. if it success, refactor your code as you wish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you never set the TimeZone.Set the Timezone first then run Hope it useful for you.

```
    //gets the default TimeZone

    DateTimeZone dateTimeZone= DateTimeZone.getDefault();
```