# Bizarre Java SQL Timestamp Calendar retrieval behaviour - takes milliseconds from Calendar?

Tags: java, sql, calendar, timestamp

This code snippet:

```
private Date fetchTimestampFromDatabase(SqlRowSet rs, String field) {

try {

  System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp(field));
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp(field, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))));
    Thread.sleep(200);
    ...
```

Gives the following result:

```
2014-06-06 10:44:58.696
2014-06-06 12:44:58.75
2014-06-06 12:44:58.95
2014-06-06 12:44:58.15
2014-06-06 12:44:58.35
2014-06-06 12:44:58.55
2014-06-06 12:44:58.75
2014-06-06 12:44:58.95
2014-06-06 12:44:58.15
2014-06-06 12:44:58.35
2014-06-06 12:44:58.55
```

Great, the timezone offset is correctly applied, but why on earth are the milliseconds being jiggled, presumably taken from the calendar instance?

Reading the javadoc of the method, I found a rather ambiguous statement that seems to imply this is behaving as specified:

> "This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate millisecond value for the timestamp"

Line 6180 of [the source file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/0c738a3e5791/src/share/classes/com/sun/rowset/CachedRowSetImpl.java) confirms this:

```
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, defaultCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, defaultCal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, defaultCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, defaultCal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, defaultCal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, defaultCal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
return new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime().getTime());
```

Does anyone know why the Calendar.MILLISECOND aren't being set?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The documentation does seem to indicate that the millisecond value is expected to be provided in the Calendar.
However, it is somewhat different than the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getTimestamp%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Calendar%29) of ResultSet (from which RowSet extends).

> This method uses the given calendar to construct an appropriate
>   millisecond value for the timestamp if the underlying database does
>   not store timezone information.

This seems to tie 2 seemingly unrelated concepts together - presence of timezone information in the database and precision of the timestamp field in the database.

The problem in the source code actually starts just before the calendar population:

```
   defaultCal.setTime((java.util.Date)value);
```

By casting the Timestamp to a java.util.Date, all the partial second data was lost. As described in the [Timestamp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html) javadoc:

> Note: This type is a composite of a java.util.Date and a separate
>   nanoseconds value. Only integral seconds are stored in the
>   java.util.Date component.