# Converting Epoch Time in EST to UTC - Java

Tags: java, sql, timestamp

I get a java.sql.Timestamp object from a resultset and I want to get the epoch time in UTC format from that timestamp.

rs.getTimestamp("columnLabel").getTime() gives me epoch time in milliseconds in EST format. I want the result to be in UTC.

Comment: "epoch time in milliseconds in EST format" Milliseconds from epoch are not in a particular timezone, it is the number of milliseconds since a specific point in time, which is invariant to timezone.

Comment: Oh yes I get it. I have a Timestamp and I need to set the timezone of that timestamp to "UTC"  and then get the time from that UTC timestamp in milli seconds.

Comment: [java.sql.Timestamp.getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#getTime()) "Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Timestamp object.". What else do you need to do?

Comment: @VinodhRavi No you don't get it. The epoch time returned by `getTime()` **is** in UTC/GMT. There is no timezone in Java dates (pre-Java 8 anyway).

Comment: The timestamp I have is "2015-11-09 04:30:00.0". When I call getTime() on this timestamp I get 1447061400000. The UTC equivalent timestamp for "1447061400000" is "2015-11-09 09:30:00.0". can you see my problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java ResultSet how to getTimeStamp in UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469256/java-resultset-how-to-gettimestamp-in-utc)